# How do I use OpenSSL with WinSock?

Tags: ssl, openssl, winsock

I've scoured the web and have not found anything for this...

Does anyone have a simple code sample of using WinSock with OpenSSL? I am looking for a simple Visual C++ 2005 or greater code sample that creates and opens a winsock connection and applies the necessary SSL settings using OpenSSL and frees all resources appropriately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Back in 2002 I wrote an article for Windows Developer Magazine that showed how to use OpenSSL to provide SSL for MFC's CAsyncSocket. The [code and article](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2010/10/using-openssl-with-asynchronous-sockets.html) and might help you though it does go further than you might need in that the main focus is not the winsock integration but using OpenSSL with asynchronous winsock. I've used this as the basis of [integrating OpenSSL with an I/O completion based high performance winsock server](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html).

Comment: I got it working, your articles had some useful bits, thanks!