# Easiest way to add SSL to a IOCP based windows server?

Tags: ssl, winsock, iocp

I have a IOCP based server which we have used for  long time. Now we need to add SSL support to this. I am struggling to find a clean solution. I have found two options suggested in the other two threads -

1) Use openssl Memory BIO - but have not found any examples on the net that work with IOCP ports which explain the issues that will arrise due to the multi threaded nature of IOCP.
2) Use Boost ASIO with ssl - which i think uses IOCP internally. But there are no examples that show how per connection state data can be stored - for example in our server there is state information stored for each client that is connected , this state information is used to recognise the client and parse sent by client data accordingly.

I would be really grateful if you could suggest a solution to the above two problems or any other solution that has worked for you.

UPDATE : I am using Simple C to implement IOCP in winsock2 library.

Best Regards
Niladri

Comment: Please update your question and describe what platform and development tools / programming language you are asking solution for.

Answer (score 2):

See my answer here: [How do I use OpenSSL with WinSock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008798/how-do-i-use-openssl-with-winsock/1011301#1011301)

I wrote an article which has code for using OpenSSL with async sockets. The article's code shows MFC's async sockets but the theory is the same for IOCP.

I used a variation on the design presented in the article for the OpenSSL support that's available as part of my IOCP based server framework; see here: http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-ssltls-using-openssl-option.html.